# Integer separated by comma

Tags: regex

What's the best regular expression for integer separated by comma?  It can also contain space between comma, and the field is not required which means it could be blank.

```
123,98549
43446
```

etc..

Comment: Mandatory JWZ quote "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: @Microspino: the coma is what people go into trying to get the regex to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very basic one that might suit you:

```
/^[\d\s,]*$/
```

It'll match any string as long as it only contains numbers, spaces and commas. It means that "123 456" will pass, but I don't know if that's a problem.

```
/^\s*(\d+(\s*,\s*\d+)*)?\s*$/
```

This one has these results:

```
""                true
"123"             true
"123, 456"        true
"123,456  , 789"  true
"123 456"         false
"   "             true
"  123   "        true
", 123 ,"         false
```

Explanation:

```
/^\s*(\d+(\s*,\s*\d+)*)?\s*$/
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9  a b c d

1. ^   Matches the start of the string
2. \s  Matches a space  * means any number of the previous thing
3. (   Opens a group
4. \d  Matches a number. + means one or more of the previous thing
5. (   Another group
6. \s* 0 or more spaces
7. ,   A comma
8. \s* 0 or more spaces
9. \d+ 1 or more numbers
a. *   0 or more of the previous thing. In this case, the group starting with #5
b. ?   Means 0 or 1 of the previous thing. This one is the group at #3
c. \s* 0 or more spaces
d. $   Matches the end of the string
```

Comment: Very nice result set. What tool do you use to get these? Thanks!

Comment: @eKek0 - I just typed them into Firebug.

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm. Now i have to go through your code t understand the reason. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a list of integers: `(\d+)`

The comma and whitespaces shouldn't be an issue, since you only need to go over the groups.

Comment: I think he wants to validate an input.

Comment: Sorry i might not express clearly my question, I want to validate an expression like "12, 3455" or "4456,888, 23343" etc. your solution just accept numbers. Thanks for reply anyway

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean with the field

> is not required which means it could
>   be blank

Besides that, I think this sould work

```
/^((\b)*[0-9]+(\b)*[,])*(\b)*[0-9]+(\b)$/
```

Comment: you need to check for the start and end of the string. This one returns true for "123,hello"

Answer (score 0):

This question should be more precise : for example, do you accept spaces between digits? do you accept comma at start/end? do you accept space before comma? do you accept several consecutive spaces? do you accept spaces at start/end ?

I will assume what I think is the most probable, so that you don't accept spaces between digits, you don't accept comma at start/end, but you accept space before and after comma, you accept several consecutive spaces and you accept spaces at start/end.

```
/^ *([0-9]+( *, *[0-9]+)*)? *$/
```

- "" : true
- "      " : true
- "123" : true
- "123,45" : true
- "123 ,45, 67" : true
- "   123" : true
- "1  2   3" : false
- ",45" : false
- "123," : false

The key when writing regex to match a list of elements "E" delimited by a separator "S" is that you'll certainly have to write the "E" matcher twice (here it is simply "[0-9]+").

- the principle of the pattern is E(SE)*
- E is "[0-9]+" : simply a sequence of digits
- S is " *, *" (notice the spaces) : a comma with optionnal spaces before and after

at this point we have :

```
/^[0-9]+( *, *[0-9]+)*$/
```

we improves it a little, so it also accepts spaces at start/end, spaces-only and empty strings :

```
/^ *([0-9]+( *, *[0-9]+)*)? *$/
```

Note I personally prefer to use [0-9] instead of \d, I think it is less confusing to read.